# Why is "Run on Server" not an option?

Tags: eclipse, server

Sorry everyone, I have been troubleshooting this one for a couple days with no luck. Run on Server is not an option for my Dynamic Web Project in eclipse. Tomcat v10.1 is installed as the server. Dynamic Web Module and Java are selected under Project Facets. I tried changing that from "custom" to "default configuration" for tomcat, but the changes will not save. And the appropriate server is selected under targeted runtimes.

A little backstory, I had Tomcat v8.5 installed, but was having a ton of issues with it so I deleted it and downloaded the most recent version. The old Dynamic Web Project that I had created under Tomcat 8.5 still has Run on Server as an option (even though the servlets for that project all now have errors), but any newly created DWPs don't. Obviously, I'm very new to this and I can't seem to find anything other than the above suggestions that I've already tried. Anyone? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which version of Eclipse is it? Which versions of the facets are set?

Comment: I actually got it to work, thank you. I had to uninstall and then reinstall everything, but now it's doing what it's supposed to do.